# Coupled system of first-order nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a coupled system of first-order ODEs.

\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} &= A + B - C\frac{x(t)}{x(t) + y(t)} + Ex(t)\\
\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} &= D + F - G\frac{y(t)}{x(t) + y(t)}
\end{align}

I tried to decouple it by bringing the system in the matrix format $\displaystyle \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = A\mathbf{x}$ but for this system Matrix $A$ would not comprise constant terms.

Here, $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ are all constants.

I have also put this software in Mathematica and MUPAD and neither can solve it in the present form. How can I decouple these equations and solve the first one analytically and then replace the solution with the other ODE?

[image]

Comment: Are constants $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $F$, $G$ independent or there is some connection between them?

Comment: These constants have a relationship between each other, i.e. $E=2C$, but there is no dependence on the state variables $x(t), y(t)$.

Comment: I believe if $G(A+B-C)+C(D+F)=0$ then system can be solved.

Comment: What happens though if $G(A+B-C)+C(D+F) \neq 0$ (which is the case in my problem)?

Comment: For a numerical experiment, I have used a simpler version of the system:

\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{x(t)}{x(t) + y(t)} \\
\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} &= \frac{y(t)}{x(t) + y(t)}
\end{align}

I have written this command in Mathematica 11.3

`sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (x[t]/(x[t] + y[t])), 
   y'[t] == (y[t]/(x[t] + y[t])), x[0] == 1, y[0] ==  50}, {x, 
   y}, {t, 0, 100}] `

and I receive the output shown in the Figure

At this point, I don't know what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing that $CG \neq0$. First take $w=Gx+Cy$ to get
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} &= A + B - C^2\frac{x}{(C-G)x + w} + 2Cx\\
\displaystyle \frac{dw}{dt} &= CD + CF - CG + GA + GB + G2Cx
\end{align}
Now take $z=CD + CF - CG + GA + GB + G2Cx\equiv mx+n$, that is $x=(z-n)/m$, and find
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{m}\frac{dz}{dt} &= A + B - C^2\frac{(z-n)}{(C-G)(z-n) + mw} + 2C(z-n)/m\\
\displaystyle \frac{dw}{dt} &= z
\end{align}
So you get a second order ODE for $w$ alone:
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{m}w'' &= A + B - C^2\frac{(w'-n)}{(C-G)(w'-n) + mw} + 2C(w'-n)/m\\
\end{align}
From which you obtain
\begin{align}
\displaystyle x &= \frac{w'-n}{m} \\
\displaystyle y &= \frac{w-Gx}{C}
\end{align}
once you have a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Diego. I did try to parse the expression for the second order ODE in Matlab LiveScript utilizing MUPAD in the background.  Is it possible to provide a format that can be parsed efficiently in MUPAD/Mathematica? I am new into solving ODEs with software and I do not understand what the problem might be